# Most of the foreign remittance come or comes?

Tags: sentence-construction, structure

1. Most of the foreign remittance come from RMG sector.
   or
2. Most of the foreign remittance comes from RMG sector.

Which one is right? Should I use "s" after come? Can anyone elaborate for me?

Comment: 1) Most of the money was spent. 2) Most of what he says is true.  3) most, some, half + of + singular noun => singular verb

Comment: I think you want plural "**remittances**". A single remittance is "a sum of money sent in payment or as a gift". So a statement about "most" of the "things" refers to multiple events.

Comment: @Nigel - If there is only one remittance, and most of the money in that remittance came from the RMG sector, then the sentence would be okay as is.

Comment: @J.R. - I agree; I was too absolute. Sentence 2 is grammatically correct, but I think it's _probably_ not the meaning the OP intended.

Answer (score 10):

The rule is a rather simple one. With a determiner like *most*, whether the verb is singular or plural depends entirely on what comes right after the preposition *of*. If it's a noun or a noun phrase that's plural, use a plural verb. Otherwise, use a singular verb. For example:

> Most of **the people** who live here **don't like** the newly-elected mayor. (*the people* is plural, use a plural verb)
>
> Most of **the work** on this project **was done** by Mike and me. (*the work* is singular, use a singular verb)

In your sentence, *the foreign remittance* is a noun phrase that's singular. So, you need an *s* at end of *come*:

> Most of the foreign remittance **comes** from the RMG sector.

Also notice that it's better to place a definite article before *RMP sector* since we're talking about a very specific sector. As Nigel Touch mentioned in his comment, a single remittance is "a sum of money sent in payment or as a gift", so if you are referring to payments in general you should use the plural "remittances":

> Most of the foreign remittances **come** from the RMG sector.